# Error while decrypting HSM keys using nCipherKM

Tags: java, encryption, hsm

I am trying to decrypt Database password stored in a Securestorage file. I am using the nCipherKM HSM security provider and the Key Encryption Keys used for decryption is stored in a key store (folder). While I try to load the HSM Key Store by passing the keystore password , it fails to load the key store with the following Exception. Not sure what is the root cause of this error.

Code Snippet:

```
java.security.provider hsm_provider = (java.security.provider)Class.forName("com.ncipher.provider.km.nCipherKM").newInstance();  
java.security.Security.addProvider(hsm_provider);  
myKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaulttype,"nCipherKM");  
myKeyStore .load(new FileInputStream(KeyStorePath),pwdOfKeyStore);
```

Exception:

> java.io.IOException: **A password was supplied but all keys are
>   module** protected.   at
>   com.ncipher.provider.km.KMKeyStore.engineLoad()

Answer (score 2):

Note: Posting this answer to an old question in the hopes of helping others who encounter this same problem.

The root cause could be that the keystore was created with the option to protect the keys with the module.  This doesn't mean that a passphrase is optional, it means it is prohibited.

To fix, use the code below

```
java.security.provider hsm_provider = (java.security.provider)Class.forName("com.ncipher.provider.km.nCipherKM").newInstance();  
java.security.Security.addProvider(hsm_provider);  
myKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaulttype,"nCipherKM");  
myKeyStore .load(new FileInputStream(KeyStorePath),null);
```

Note: if you attempt to extract the private key from the keystore, you should pass in a null too, like the following:

```
PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey)keystore.getKey(KEYSTORE_ALIAS, null);
```